# Concatenated Formula Field to Plain Text

Tags: formula, formula-field, visual-workflow

I have a FORMULA field which concatenates a few other fields and displays them with line breaks:

```
"Letters:" & Letters__c & BR() & 
"Numbers:" & "Numbers__c" & BR() & 
"Symbols:" & Symbols__c
```

What I expect to see is something like this:

```
AAA
123
!@#
```

And I do. However, when I use a flow to update this result into a LONG TEXT field I get this:

```
LettersBR()NumbersBR()SymbolsBR().
```

I can't convert the receiving field to RICH TEXT. Any work arounds?

Comment: Is the formula field updating correctly?

Comment: I suspect you need to use either line feed or carriage return symbols in your code which would be `\n` and `\r` respectively in order to use them with rich text which I'd expect to properly recognize them as character escapes. If not, you'd need to get the unicode equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

Type : Text   | API : Letters__c | Value : ABC

Type : Number | API : Numbers__c | Value : 123

Type : Text | API : Symbols__c | Value : !@#

Type : Formule(Text) | API : Result__c

**Formula Field** | **Result__c** : "Letters: " & Letters__c & BR() & "Numbers: " & TEXT(Numbers__c) & BR() & "Symbols: " & Symbols__c

You will definitely get the require output in Long Text field using field update flow.